# Factor of a product is product of factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

I'm trying to prove the uniqueness of prime factorization of any natural number $n\ge 2$ (I take $0\in\mathbb N$). I've shown the existence of a prime factorization for any such number (by infinite descent on the statement that 'for each $n\ge 2$, there exists a greatest prime that divides $n$').

To show uniqueness, I realize that I will be done if I can show that
$$
\forall a\;\forall b\;\forall c\;\left(c\text{ divides } ab\implies\exists m\;\exists n\; (m\text{ divides } a\;\wedge\; n\text{ divides } b\;\wedge\; c=mn)\right).
$$

But after a lot of futile attempts, I'm not able to "see" any path leading me to this statement. Any help?

---

**Note:** I haven’t proven Euclid’s division lemma, and am not working with gcd’s. Hence I’ll appreciate a way that avoids these.

Comment: Hint : Assume $m$ is the smallest positive integer having no unique factorization. Then show that the factorizations cannot share a prime factor (since then a smaller number would have no unique factorization). The rest should be easy. If not, I can give another hint.

Comment: @Peter I can see that the prime factorizations a the smallest such number will have no common prime factors. But I don't know what to do next. (I haven't yet proven that if a prime $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides either $a$ or $b$.)

Comment: As stated, the claim is false (e.g., when $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=30$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh, thanks for pointing it out! I meant $c$ divides $ab$ and not vice-versa. Corrected now.

Comment: The assertion "If a prime $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides either $a$ or $b$" is known as Euclid's Lemma and is essential to prove unique factorization.

Comment: @jjagmath Yea, I realized that Euclid's Lemma follows from my statement. But I can't think of a proof.

Comment: By the way, since you can find a proof of Euclid's Lemma (and the unique factorization theorem) in any Number Theory textbook, this kind of questions are discouraged in this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove your displayed assertion by strong induction on $c$.  The assertion is clearly true for the base case $c=1$ (with $m=n=1$).  So assume it's true for all $c'\lt c$, where $c\gt1$. Let $p$ be any prime divisior of $c$ and write $c=pc'$, noting that $p\gt1$ implies $c'\lt c$.. Since $p\mid c\mid ab$, we know (by Euclid's lemma) that $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. Without loss of generality, let's assume it's $p\mid a$, and write $a=pa'$. We find now that $c'\mid a'b$, hence, by the strong induction hypothesis, there exist integers $m'$ and $n$ such that $m'\mid a'$, $n\mid b$, and $m'n=c'$. Now simply let $m=pm'$ and note that $m'\mid a'\implies m=pm'\mid pa'=a$ and $c=pc'=pm'n=mn$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a proof which doesn’t use Euclid’s lemma. (I haven’t proven it yet. In fact, I’m trying to proven uniqueness of prime factorisation using my mentioned statement.)

Comment: @Atom, ah, I'll see if I can think of a non-euclidean work-around.  You might, though, want to edit the question to make clear how many hands you want to tie around your back.

Comment: Edited. Thanks tons for giving time to my question!

Answer (score -1):

**Proof of the uniqueness of prime factorization :**

Let's suppose we have two factorizations : $p_1 ^{\alpha_1}...p_r ^{\alpha_r} = q_1 ^{\beta_1}...q_t ^{\beta_t}$.

Then for $1\leqslant i \leqslant r$, we have $p_i | q_1 ^{\beta_1}...q_t ^{\beta_t}$, and the $q_l$ are prime, so there exists one $1\leqslant j \leqslant t$ such that $p_i | q_j$ so $p_i = q_j$.

By doing the same with the $q_j$, we get that $\{p_1,...,p_r\} = \{q_1,...q_l\}$ and as all the $p_i$ and $q_j$ are different, we have that $r=l$.

We can then reorder the $(p_i)$ and $(q_j)$ to have $p_i = q_i$.

Let's prove we have $\alpha_i=\beta_i$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant r$.

For $1\leqslant i\leqslant r$, $p_i^{\alpha_i} |q_1 ^{\beta_1}...q_r ^{\beta_r}$ and by Gauss Lemm, since $p_i$ is prime with all the $q_j$ for $j\geqslant 2$, we have $p_i^{\alpha_i} | q_i^{\beta_i} = p_i^{\beta_i}$, and we can do the same with $q_i$, so $p_i^{\alpha_i} = p_i^{\beta_i}$.

So $\alpha_i = \beta_i$, and this for all $i$.

Then the decomposition is unique.

**For a proof of Euclid Lemma :**

Let's suppose there exists $p$ prime and $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p$ does not divide $a$ and $b$, but $p|ab$. Let's take, for $p$ and $a$ given, among all the possibilities of $b$, the smallest.

Then $0<b<p$ (because if not we could replace $b$ by a smaller one). We note $r$ the rest of Euclid's division of $p$ by $b$, which is not null since $p$ is prime.
Then $p=mb+r$ so $ar = ap -mab$ is a multiple of $p$.

But we know that $0<r<b<p$ so $ar$ is not a multiple of $p$ because of the minimality of $p$.

So we've got a contradiction, and that proves Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, your proof uses Euclid's Lemma (which follows from my statement), which I haven't proven yet.
Also, I'll be done if I can prove my statement.

Comment: i didn't understand the proposition you want top prove there are two divides ?